# Mod_rewrite rewrite URL rules does nothing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get my apache to clean up my ugly url's.

I know that mod_rewrite works because I have tried it with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oranges.html$ apples.html
```

And it shows the apples.html page.

I am trying to use this but it doesn't do anything!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

I want this url: http://example.com/index.php?page=search

To look like this: http://example.com/search/

What could be wrong here? :o

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]*$ index.php?page=$1
```

Note the +FollowSymLinks option which is mandatory for rewriting to work and the -Multiviews which can mess with rewriting.

I've also tuned your rule to make the trailing slash optional

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work either. There must be some config/option I have not activated or something? So weird...

Comment: mod_rewrite should obviously be activated but if it wasn't, you would get an error 500

Comment: Does your server allows .htaccess files at all? Try typing garbage in it and see if it throws an error

Comment: Yes. If I type garbage in .htaccess file I get an 500 error. So it does read from the file, but I can't rewrite the url's. I have tried to solve this for days with different rules I found on google etc. I have to get this fixed soon  :/. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try adding -Multiviews in the Options line, Multiview messes with rewriting rules big time

Comment: Try adding the rewritebase too

Answer (score 0):

If the index.php is not at the DocumentRoot level ensure the relative url forms part of the rule e.g. in my case I had a public directory.

```
Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```